# Concat and Uglify JS Files from Two Different Sources using Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have different sets of JS files that I want to concat and uglify. One is for the app, one is for the website. My gruntfile.js looks something like the one below. The problem is that only the `website` one runs even though I have registered the grunt task as: `grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat:app', 'concat:website', 'uglify']);`

```
concat: {
    app: {
        js: {
            src: [
            'app/js/vendor/jquery.js',
            'app/js/app/ui.js',
            'app/js/app/data.js'
        ],
            dest: 'app/js/app.js'
        },
        css: {
            src: [
            'app/css/vendor/normalize.css',
            'app/css/vendor/ui.css',
            'app/css/vendor/style.css',
        ],
            dest: 'app/css/app.css'
        }
    },
    website: {
        src: [
            'app/js/vendor/jquery.js',
            'app/js/website/scripts.js'
        ],
        dest: 'app/js/common.js'
    }
},
uglify: {
    development: {
        options: {
            preserveComments: false
        },
        files: {
            'app/js/app.min.js': 'app/js/app.js',
            'app/js/common.min.js': 'app/js/common.js'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me the issue is the fact that in `app`, I am concatenating both CSS and JS files. I removed the CSS block and it ran fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

concat can concatenate multiple files and types in the same target, but you have to use the proper grunt syntax (https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-concat#multiple-files-per-target):

```
concat: {
  app: {
    'app/js/app.js': [
        'app/js/vendor/jquery.js',
        'app/js/app/ui.js',
        'app/js/app/data.js'
    ],
    'app/css/app.css': [
        'app/css/vendor/normalize.css',
        'app/css/vendor/ui.css',
        'app/css/vendor/style.css',
    ],
  }
},
```